# Cache life time in LswMemcacheBundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, memcached, lsw-memcache-bundle

I decided to use LswMemcacheBundle (in Symfony2) to cache Doctrine2 queries into memcached, but I've got one problem. I can't find any information about possibility to change cache life time, even about default life time.

Is there anyone who can provide me such informations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like results cache is not enabled for all queries (but query cache is enabled) and we need to enable it using `useResultCache` method. This method also allows us to set cache life time.

So it'll look like this

```
$em->createQuery('SELECT a FROM SomeBundle:Entity a')
      ->useResultCache(true, 3600, 'cacheId')
      ->getResult();
```

and for `createQueryBuilder`

```
$repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('SomeBundle:Entity');
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('g');
$qb->andWhere('g.categoryId = :categoryId')->setParameter('categoryId', '1');
$qb->addOrderBy('g.id', 'DESC');

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$query->useResultCache(true, 3600, 'cacheId');
```

where `3600` will be cache life time in seconds and `cacheId` our cache key.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you still have to set the cache lifetime using the methods through the cacheDriver.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/caching.html#result-cache

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/caching.html#saving